# Loading Custom Dialog Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

**Hello!**

I'm working on an Angular 2 project and I'd like to implement some sort of loading feature while the website generates files.
My first thought was creating a custom dialog and putting a loader in it and having the whole thing disappear once it's done with the generation.

***Could anyone provide a simple example I could use to do this?***

***Or if anyone has a better idea for a loading feature I'm all ears.***

Thank you in advance and if you have questions don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: https://medium.com/@zeljkoradic/loader-bar-on-every-http-request-in-angular-6-60d8572a21a9

Comment: Tried following it, didn't work for me. For some reason the "providers" as written in app.component.ts comes up as unusable.

    `providers: [
      {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: LoaderInterceptorService,
        multi: true
      }
    ]`